# package.exports.types field is not working

Tags: typescript, npm, package.json

I made a simple example to test `package.exports.types` field and the settings read as follow

```json
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./build/index.js",
      "require": "./build/index.js",
      "default": "./build/index.js",
      "types": "./build/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./foo": {
      "import": "./build/foo.js",
      "require": "./build/foo.js",
      "default": "./build/foo.js",
      "types": "./build/foo.d.ts"
    },
    "./package.json": "./package.json"
  },
```

However, when I import this package in the another project, it says

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'exports-test/foo' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import * as a from 'exports-test/foo'
```

And it seems that the typescript compiler can't find the type definition file for `foo`.
My typescript version is 4.6.3. And I think I followed every instruction stated in the official document.

What is wrong with my settings? It'd be very helpful if you can share the repository of a working example.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm currently seeing the same behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might need to add the following option in your `tsconfig.json`. It works in my project.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
  }
}
```

See also: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49971#issuecomment-1192993398